# Help with hyperbolic integral $\int_0^\infty x\frac{\cosh(bx)}{\sinh(x)}dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, potential-theory

The Integral Calculator couldn't help me with the following integral:

> $$\int_0^\infty x\frac{\cosh(bx)}{\sinh(x)}dx.$$

From some mathematical physics considerations, I get that the answer should be of the form: $\dfrac{const}{1-cos(b)}$. Is it true? Could you, please, help me with intermediate steps?

Comment: It should go to $\infty$ as $b\to1$, so it's certainly not $C/(1-\cos b)$.

Comment: $b\in(-1,1)$ atleast for the integral to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** One way is using [$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin ax}{\sinh x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh(\frac{\pi a}{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550932/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sinax-sinhxdx-with-a-rectangular-con?rq=1), then differentiating respect to $a$ gives an answer with $a=ib$.

Comment: Also the answer is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}\dfrac{1}{1-\cos\pi b}$